# SQL Query to count number of rows searched until condition is met

Tags: php, mysql

Just as the title says, I need a query to count the rows until the condition is met. Here's my setup:

```
partnumber
-----------    
b
e
d
a
c
```

So if I'm going to search for partnumber = d it will sort the part number and return 4 (since d is the 4th when you sort the partnumber).

I can do this inside a loop. I'm just wondering if there is a query for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `select count(*) from myTable where partnumber <= 'd';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM THE_TABLE WHERE partnumber <= (SELECT ID FROM THE_TABLE WHERE partnumber <= 'd');
```

Comment: Thanks @Dagon, with little tweaks I got what I need... Would you mind telling me what "<=" means? is it literally a "greater than or equal to"? Before I visit this post again I also come up with the same query... The only difference I'm using "LIKE" rather than "<="...

Comment: LESS than or equal to d, ie  equal to a,b,c,d

Comment: Ooopss... Yeah Less than  or equal to... But why does it work? I'm sorry for the question, I just want to understand the logic behind it... I haven't use the <= to a string before...

Comment: its a common practice, every language i know understands the English alphabet and sorts a-z and understands the order of letters jusrt as it understands the order of numbers - sorry not a very technical answer.